# incorrect syntax near the keyword 'DECLARE' when creating a View

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I'm having trouble creating a View on SSMS. If I run a query, it runs fine, but I'm not able to save it as a view.
Here are the first few lines as I don't think the rest will be too relevant:

```
DECLARE @dayName VARCHAR(9)
DECLARE @current INT
DECLARE @previous INT
SET @dayName = DATEName(DW, GETDATE())

IF
(@dayName = 'Saturday') 
BEGIN
SET @current = 1
SET @previous = 2
END

ELSE IF
(@dayName = 'Sunday') 
BEGIN
SET @current = 2
SET @previous = 3
END

ELSE 
IF(@dayName = 'Monday')
BEGIN
SET @current = 0
SET @previous = 3
END


SELECT DATE, BRAND, MODEL, EAN, SUPPLIER_CATEGORY, FAMILY, FAMILY_PER_EAN, SUM(UNITS) AS UNITS
FROM ...
```

Then when I try to save it into a View I get the following error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'DECLARE'

Can you let me know what I'm doing wrong.Thanks.

Comment: You can't declare variables in views. Use `stored procedure` or `function` instead.

Comment: Did you declare those variables in the view? if so, you can't do that cause the view always expect `SELECT` statement, mybe you can reverse to a function instead.

Comment: Variables are not supported inside a view in SQL Server.  
You can only use a single SELECT statement (including common table expressions).

Answer (score 2):

You are correct. Local variables are not allowed in a VIEW.

You can set a local variable in a table valued function, which returns a result set (like a view does.)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can not create `View` on this script. Take a look on the following topic:

[CREATE VIEW (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

You have to create `Stored Procedre` or `Multi-Statement Table-Valued Function` in sql server:

[CREATE PROCEDURE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

[CREATE FUNCTION (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

The point is, you can `select` on `Multi-Statement Table-Valued Function` but if you want to select on `Stored Procedure` you have use open query. However, i suggest you that do not use open query.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is clear, you have an incorrect syntax, please see **[CREATE VIEW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** syntax and examples.

If you really need to use those variables, you can use a **[`StoredProcedure`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)**, or even a **[`function`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)**.